# How to execute a compiled code snipped in Frege online repl

Tags: frege

OK, I guess this is a stupid beginners question:

I try to learn Frege through the online repl. For doing so, I though it would be a good idea to paste code examples from [Dierk's Real World Frege](https://github.com/Dierk/Real_World_Frege) to the upper right window of the repl, press compile and... ? How do I start this code?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I partly found the answer myself:

the `:java` command in the command line shows the generated code. Within this code, it is visible that the compiled module is automatically imported, so we don't have to reference it.

Now, if we take the HelloWorld example from the repl, it is simply executed by typing

```
frege> main
```

into the left window.

Dierk uses for his examples the syntax

```
main _ = do
```

If we now type

```
frege> main
```

we only get

```
:: a -> IO ()
```

as output. But if we type

```
frege> main "something"
```

the repl gives the expected output. While I still don't know what's going on, this helps me with my next steps :-)

Comment: Indeed! For compatibility with Java, "main" can be declared like `[String] -> IO ()` and for compatibility with Haskell, it can be just `IO ()`. Depending on that you call main.

Comment: To avoid confusion, please observe the following 1.) Use different module names every time, or use the `:reset` command to clear old stuff. 2.) Don't use unqualified module names, there might be some issues (due to JVM restrictions) with them.

Comment: You've got it absolutely correct. The modules and definitions are loaded automatically in the REPL on the left (In fact, they both share the same session). A "Run" button would definitely make it easier for modules.