# Problems with Code in the Frege REPL

Tags: frege

While trying to learn Frege I copied some code from [Dierk's Real World Frege](https://github.com/Dierk/Real_World_Frege) to the online REPL an tried to execute it (see also [How to execute a compiled code snipped in Frege online repl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33926012/how-to-execute-a-compiled-code-snipped-in-frege-online-repl)). The scripts I've tried don't compile :-(

What am I doing wrong?

Here are examples of what does not compile:

```
println ( 2 *-3 )       -- unlike haskell, this will work!
```

and the whole [ValuesAndVariables.fr](https://github.com/Dierk/Real_World_Frege/blob/master/realworld/chapter1/ValuesAndVariables.fr) code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unavoidable that over the course of more than a year, an evolving language (and its libraries) change so that older code will not compile anymore.

It would be nice, if we could see an example, instead of a generalization like "most".

The next best thing would be to have an issue in Dierks project that points to the error(s).

But the very best would be en effort to find out what is wrong. This would also intensify your learning process.

Here are two ressources that could help:

https://github.com/Frege/frege/wiki/New-or-Changed-Features -- the release notes for every release, contains a summary of things that have changed between releases, and especially the reasons why code would not compile anymore and how to correct it.

http://www.frege-lang.org/doc/fregedoc.html -- the library docs. May explain possible errors like import not found, or missing identifiers.

Go, give it a try. And I'm convinced Dierk will be happy to accept pull requests.

### Edit: Fixes for announced errors.

The error in:

```
println ( 2 *-3 )
```

stems indeed from a syntactical change. 
It is, as of recently, demanded that adjacent operators be separated by at least one space.
Hence

```
println (2 * -3)
```

However, the error message you got here was:

```
can't resolve `*-`, did you mean `-` perhaps?
```

which could have triggered the idea that it tries to interpret `*-` as a single operator.

The other error in `ValuesAndVariables1.fr` is indeed a show stopper for a beginner. The background is that we have one `pi` that has type `Double` and one that has type `Float` and potentially many more through type class `Floating`, so one needs to tell which one to print.
The following will work:

```
import Prelude.Math    -- unless already imported
println Float.pi
println (pi :: Double)
```

Comment: Thanx for this detailed answer. You are absolutely right. I don't the the change in the language as a problem, but people who start looking at it should be aware of it :-) as soon as I progress with my learning, I will start pull requests... Promised!

Comment: That would be great. That being said, a question like "why does **this** code not compile?" is absolutly in order, and will get you help quickly (but you're the type that wants to find out for himself, I have the feeling. Very good!). Yet, judge by yourself, nobody can tell you the concrete reason why **most** code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

the online REPL at http://try.frege-lang.org is currently based on Frege V3.23.370-g898bc8c . Dierk's code examples are based on V3.21.500-g88270a0 (which can be seen in the gradle build file).

It seems that the Frege developers decided to change the Frege syntax slightly between those versions. THe result is that you will not be able to run these code snippets in the online REPL anymore.

Comment: The project is updated to the latest Frege version as of now: https://github.com/Dierk/Real_World_Frege/commit/4990299eeaa6358751eb780bec3ddb125565a413. However, the code will never compile against _all_ versions. So it is better to use the provided gradle build automation for compiling.

Comment: wow. great. awesome. thanx! Would it make sense to state the frege version used in the header of the code?